# Play Store not displaying local currency in payment window

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, currency, google-play-console

We are trying to publish an app on android play store with in-app purchases, but we have been blocked for days by a currency problem.

The Google account is based in Ukraine and we entered a payment method in the form of an Ukrainian currency (Hryvnia) account. As a result, the prices of IAP items had to be entered in Hryvnia.
When the player wants to make an in-app purchase, Google does send us a price in the player's local currency (e.g. Euro in France) which we display in the game. But then, when the Google payment window is displayed, the price is in Hryvnia and not in the local currency, which is not convenient for us.

**What should we do to make sure that Google displays the price in the local currency?**

PS: We asked the question a week ago at the play store support, but we didn't get an answer. Is it always like that?

Answer (score 0):

For information, if others have the same problem: we didn't understand why it didn't work (we strongly think it's a bug in the play console because the "update taxes" button is not working) but we found a workaround: by using template prices instead of direct prices for the IAP items, it works almost correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem with a new app. Clicking `Update exchange rates` didn't help either.

The solution seems to be to upload a preview of the app already and add it to the "Closed testing" track:

1. Choose `Testing -> Closed Testing` in the navigation bar:

[image: Testing -> Closed testing in the navbar]

2. Click on `Manage track` right next to the Alpha track, then create a new release and upload your App Bundle / APK or choose an existing one.
3. `Review` the release and fix potential upcoming errors*. You can ignore the warnings for now.
4. You can now go back and the price calculation should work immediately. You don't need to wait for the release to being reviewed.

I don't know why an existing Alpha track is required, but I don't think that this is intended. I sent a small feedback form to the Google Play Developer Console support team.

<sub>*: If there is an error about no regions being selected, go back to the "Alpha" track page and choose at least one region in the `Countries/regions` tab.</sub>