# Google play does not show local prices for in-app products

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase

I uploaded signed SDK and created internal testing track. Then I created and activated new in-app product. However, when I enter default price, I am not able to see any local prices in different currencies. Instead I see only empty table with *"No results"*, clicking on *update* does not help. Please see
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQXag.png) for reference.

This gives me feeling I missed something. As far as I know I should be able to see current prices in other currencies.

Comment: I'm getting this as well. Interestingly, if I go to "manage pricing templates" and create a pricing template there, the exchange rates are shown.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently, problem is not only in google play console, but also in payment window in app, which does not show local prices. Using pricing templates solves this, as reported also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65476790/play-store-not-displaying-local-currency-in-paiement-window)

Comment: I just answered that linked question (as it's older than yours) and as this question here seems to be the same but newer, maybe we should close it as duplicate? I hope the answer over there helps.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the help! I had only internal testing track, strange it didn't worked with that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue happens because draft builds do not have countries selected for distribution. Just open the Open or Closed track and select all countries. After that, you would be able to set up country-specific prices even for Draft build.
[image]